# AMD 7730M Ubuntu 15.04 Problems Dell Inspiron 15R SE 7520

Tags: 15.04, ati

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop Dell Inspiron 15R SE 7520, even installing the proprietary drivers from the AMD website and I am with the following problems:

1. Overheating(+70.c);
2. Low battery life time (less than 1: 30h);
3. Low graphs score in Steam;
4. Often the system does not start, it is in black screen.

My Hardware:

Dell Inspiron 15R 7520 SE;
Processor Intel Core I7 3612QM;
Memory Ram 16GB;
Grafics: AMD Radeon 7730M & Intel HD4000(Hybrid)
Hard Disk 512SSD

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine that you installed 15.04 after 15.10 was released one week ago.

I **assume** that you meant that you have installed the new edition **Ubuntu 15.10** !

This might be a result from AMD Catalyst driver having issues with kernel 4.2.

That is a known issue : [A Fix For AMD Catalyst On Ubuntu 15.10 Is Coming](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-15.10-fglrx-Fix).

Uninstall the AMD proprietary drivers (preferable from a virtual console) :
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password ...

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx  
sudo reboot
```

There is a workaround fix in wily-proposed but it is recommended to wait until it is tested.
Use the open source radeon drivers in the meantime until the final Catalyst fix is released.

Comment: According https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1493888, this fix is actually released

Comment: @Kwaadpepper : yes - as I said in my answer ... There is a workaround fix in wily-proposed ... :)

Comment: Hello , I not installed Ubuntu 10.15 because it is not possible to install the video driver, and my games do not work as well as very hot and the battery does not last. I continue with the problem....